# AlphaAnimation doesn't work on Gingerbread phones?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view, android-2.3-gingerbread

The following code fades a View out in Ice Cream Sandwich phones but not on Gingerbread phones:

```
myView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
alphaAnimation.setDuration(3000);

myView.startAnimation(alphaAnimation);
```

... Anyone have any idea why this might be??

> **Note:** I've tried the `View.setAnimation(alphaAnimation)` method as well as explicitly calling the `alphaAnimation.start()` method but both also fail on Gingerbread phones.

Comment: Try providing startoffset for the animation.

Comment: `AlphaAnimation` definitely works on Gingerbread. Your particular stretch of code there, though, seems strange, trying to simultaneously make it visible and invisible.

Comment: Deepak, unfortunately setting start offset as 0 or 1000 or any value has no effect.

Comment: CommonsWare, I only want the `View` to be visible for the duration of the animation. (I set its visibility to `GONE` when the animation ends via an `AnimationListener`, but didn't want to over-complicate my question so omitted this.)

Answer (score 0):

Try providing startoffset for the animation.

Also are you sure that your view myView is on top of the other views? The animation may be running but may not be visible because it may be below other views.

Comment: `setStartOffset(...)` does not fix it. And the `View` being animated does have another `View` on top of it but the `View` above has a transparent background. The animated `View` shows on Ice Cream Sandwich.

Answer (score 0):

Going with @CommonsWare's comment, I changed the way I'm doing my animation to not change the visibility of my `View`. In doing so, I realised that the problem was not to do with my `View`'s alpha animation but with my layout (z-ordering) irrespective of the animation.

I've posted a new question here:

[FrameLayout z-order not behaving as expected on Gingerbread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590776/framelayout-z-order-not-behaving-as-expected-on-gingerbread)

Answer (score 0):

Most gingerbread phones come with animations disabled in settings.  Check and make sure you have enabled the animations.