# FrameLayout z-order not behaving as expected on Gingerbread?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I have a layout as follows:

```
<FrameLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@android:color/black" >

<View
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@android:color/white" >

<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >
  <!-- children -->
</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

The `LinearLayout` has no background and neither do any of its children. I can see the white `View` beneath the `LinearLayout` on Ice Cream Sandwich devices but not on Gingerbread devices. Anyone know why this might be and what I can do about it??

> **Note:** I'm not setting the background of the `LinearLayout` to be white
>   as what I really need to do is perform some animations on the `View` object.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting the background of the `LinearLayout` to `@android:color/transparent` or `@null`?

Comment: Just tried it now but no luck :(

Comment: How strange. Have you tried using Hierarchy View to see if it points out anything that might be a problem, based on the whatever the `<!-- children -->` are?

Comment: I just tried running the Hierarchy Viewer and the Android Emulator. Both are horridly slow, unresponsive and the Hierarchy Viewer keeps losing touch with the Emulator. They're unusable.

Comment: Make sure that you are set up to use an x86 emulator image: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm